# PHP7.0 session handler problems (Permission denied and function table is corrupt)

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I'm on WAMP PHP7.0.11 and find that my custom file based session handler fails regularly (but not all the time), with the error

```
SessionHandler::read(): open(C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\xxxxx) failed: Permission denied (13)
```

After I encounter this, I need to restart WAMP to resolve the problem.

The error message points at the custom Session class (which extends SessionHandler) and is the read method:

```
public function read($id) {
    //return mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $this->key, parent::read($id), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);

    return $this->getDecrypt(parent::read($id), $this->key);
}
```

Also, sometimes I get the following

```
PHP Fatal error:  session_set_save_handler(): Session 
handler's function table is corrupt in... <line pointing to 
a call to "session_set_save_handler">
```

As I say, it doesn't happen every time, but maybe one in 20 page calls.
Does anyone know what might be wrong with this setup?

Comment: ...c:/Windows/Temp =local developer setup only. Encryption - the writes are encrypted with a similar pattern - any reason no to?

Comment: PS. ...c:/Windows/Temp =local developer setup only - it is the default - I did nothing to make this happen.